# Get helper in hbs when getting nested object

Tags: ember.js, handlebarshelper

suppose I have the following objects:

```js
image: {
  size: {
    l: {
      url: 'l.jpg',
    },
    m: {
      url: 'm.jpg',
    },
    s; {
      url: 's.jpg',
    }
  }
},
mySize: 'm'
```

If I want to get corresponding image url in my template, how should I do that?
I tried:

```
{{get image mySize 'url'}}
```

but it does not work.

I can get the url I want by typing like this:

```
{{get (get image mySize) 'url')}}
```

However this is a very unintuitive and ugly workaround. Is there any a better way? Thank you.

Comment: you can write your own helper

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the concat helper along with it:

`{{get image (concat 'size.' mySize '.url')}}`

But this sounds like a job for a computed property:

```
imageUrl: Ember.computed('mySize', 'image.size', function() {
  let { image, mySize } = this.getProperties('image', 'mySize');
  return Ember.get(image, `size.${mySize}.url`);
})
```

That way you can just use `{{imageUrl}}` in the template.

[Ember twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/bd86d0ff403e553fe578932eb7642f97?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I used the concat helper method and it works. Computed property sounds like a good idea, but I don't know how to use it when I have a each loop in my template. See the twiddle here: [link](https://ember-twiddle.com/bd86d0ff403e553fe578932eb7642f97?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C)

Comment: Ah if you're looping over items you can't use a computed property like that, you would have to make a component and pass the info to that component and have it handle the url, sounds like a bit of overkill if this is all you are doing.

Comment: I agree. I don't want to make a component to handle such a tiny thing, a get-concat combo will do the work. 
In my opinion, the Ember team should make the get helper to accept more then 2 arguments, then everyone will be really simple and intuitive.
Thanks again for your help!